# How to use TermQuery to do an AND query across multiple terms?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I'm am using elasticsearch using the pyes Python library.

Suppose I wanted to find all documents with title="Rainbow" AND artist="Kermit".  The following returns documents with title="Rainbow" OR artist="Kermit".  How do I change this to an AND?

```
query = pyes.TermQuery()
query.add("title", "rainbow")
query.add("artist","kermit")
search = pyes.Search(query)
results = conn.search(search, index_name, doc_type)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to wrap two TermQuery in a BooleanQuery

```
q1 = pyes.TermQuery("title", "rainbow")
q2 = pyes.TermQuery("artist", "kermit")
query = BooleanQuery(must=[q1, q2])
search = pyes.Search(query)
results = conn.search(search, index_name, doc_type)
```